# A simple console Rubik's cube in C (No need to solve, only design)

Tags: c

So, as a beginner, this program is giving me a migraine. Of course, I'm not asking for any complete code, I want to understand the logic and my options.

In university, the topics in C programming we have covered (or will cover) do not exceed Dynamic arrays. We can use structures, functions, arrays, pointers but **not classes** because this is C, not C++.

I'm good with solutions, but not puzzles. What I've tried is making a cube **struct** with 6 integers (to represent sides), and then make an array of **cube**.

Another thing I can do is make a [6][3][3] array but I think that'd make it too complex? To summarize what I'm asking,

## Requirements

- Console application
- No fancy graphics or anything
- No solution
- Simply a working cube
- Can initialize to user input

**Level: Amateur**

Is this the right approach? How do you think I should rotate a line? Again, no need for code, if you can please explain the main logic and how should I break up the code or even Pseudo-code, that'd be great.

Do you think I should make a whole cube at all using cube `rubik[3][3][3]` or deal with face like `cube face[3][3]`?

I'll add any extra information you require to help solve my problem.

EDIT - Additional Info: 
This is my cube array (the editor here messed up the indentation a bit):

```
int cube[6][3][3] = {{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}, 
            {{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2}}, 
            {{3,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}},
            {{4,4,4},{4,4,4},{4,4,4}},
            {{5,5,5},{5,5,5},{5,5,5}},
            {{6,6,6},{6,6,6},{6,6,6}}  };
```

Comment: In the future, if you have a C question, and don't want C++ answers, simply omit the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

a cube can be represented by

```
int tile[6][3][3];
```

the first index is the face of the cube

the second and the third represent the row and the column

the value of the array is the color (0-5)

---

Action that can be performed on a cube are a 90° clockwise rotation of one of the 6 faces (so 6 possible actions).

Any other lecit action can be represented by a sequence of the above.

---

For completeness, even if it's not asked, the easiest way to solve the puzzle is to bruteforce try all possible sequence of moves until a solution is found. But that would result in very inefficient usage of memory and processor. As solution is usually found in 20 moves a worst case scenario would result in trying around 1.0E14 moves...

The web has plenty of puzzle solution algorithms...

Comment: However, note that "logically easiest" != "efficient". In particular, trying "all possible sequence of moves" will lead to many move sequences that result in a state already seen before, and so will generate a huge pool of looping sequences, unless you remember every state you've already seen and compare on every move, which is going to require a *lot* of memory (20! different possible states, approximately)...

Comment: As mentioned, there is no need to SOLVE the cube, only to make it move like it should :)

Comment: @twalberg yes I agree. I'll update my answer mentioning

Answer (score 1):

Either option you have descibed will do the job.  How you break it up with logic really depends on what makes the most sense to you. What might help is to write down a list out what features a rubix cube has and rearrange until you have a way to represent each part of the object.  Your array idea is a wonderful start to this.

> ... [6][3][3] array but I think that'd make it too complex?

I thing that this makes a lot of sense and is actually fairly simple solution to your problem.  My suggestion is roll with it and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to take it on visually, basically a cube has 6 faces and each side has a 9 little squares (or a 9x9 array).

[This](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=801107) book has a few interesting ideas on how to go about representing one.

Answer (score -1):

//The code is too long so its on 2 parts.

## 1 PART

This should work:(i know it's quite long and not commented a lot but the main idea is that there are place-holders which hold the chars u-up, f-front, d-down, b-back, l-left and r-right. They can move around with the move method.
There are 2 move methods for yhe side and for the face. After that everything is drawn with draw method.

```
static void Move(ref char b0, ref char b1, ref char b2, ref char b3, ref char b4, ref char b5, ref char b6, ref char b7, ref char b8, ref char b9, ref char b10, ref char b11)
        {
            char m = b11;
            b11 = b10;
            b10 = b9;
            b9 = b8;
            b8 = b7;
            b7 = b6;
            b6 = b5;
            b5 = b4;
            b4 = b3;
            b3 = b2;
            b2 = b1;
            b1 = b0;
            b0 = m;
        }
        static void MoveSide(ref char b0, ref char b1, ref char b2, ref char b3)
        {
            char m = b3;
            b3 = b2;
            b2 = b1;
            b1 = b0;
            b0 = m;
        }
        static void Color(char p)
        {
            switch (p)
            {
                case 'u':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                break;
                case 'f':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                break;
                case 'd':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                break;
                case 'b':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                break;
                case 'l':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                break;
                case 'r':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                break;
            }
        }
```

#Part 2

```
static void Move(ref char b0, ref char b1, ref char b2, ref char b3, ref char b4, ref char b5, ref char b6, ref char b7, ref char b8, ref char b9, ref char b10, ref char b11)
            {
                char m = b11;
                b11 = b10;
                b10 = b9;
                b9 = b8;
                b8 = b7;
                b7 = b6;
                b6 = b5;
                b5 = b4;
                b4 = b3;
                b3 = b2;
                b2 = b1;
                b1 = b0;
                b0 = m;
            }
            static void MoveSide(ref char b0, ref char b1, ref char b2, ref char b3)
            {
                char m = b3;
                b3 = b2;
                b2 = b1;
                b1 = b0;
                b0 = m;
            }
            static void Color(char p)
            {
                switch (p)
                {
                    case 'u':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
                    case 'f':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    break;
                    case 'd':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    break;
                    case 'b':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    break;
                    case 'l':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    break;
                    case 'r':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    break;
                }
            }
```