# Cycling through some numbers

Tags: c

I posted a question about Rubik's cube here (You don't need to read it though): [A simple console Rubik's cube in C (No need to solve, only design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913109/a-simple-console-rubiks-cube-in-c-no-need-to-solve-only-design)

Basically, I just need help with this, so I can implement this in my Rubik's cube program. Suppose, there are 4 numbers like this `[1,2,3,4]` and I *push* from the left, so now it becomes `[4,1,2,3]`. If I push it again, it should become `[3,4,1,2]`.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is rotating a row on the cube. And my rotating function is something like this (I'm still changing this because this doesn't work that well):

```
void swapRow(int row)
{
    int placeHolder[3];  //Consider it as a 'blank' row
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            placeHolder[j] = cube[front][row][j];  

        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cube[front][row][j] = cube[front+1][row][j]; 

        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cube[front-1][row][j] = placeHolder[j]; 

}
```

This is my cube array:

```
int cube[6][3][3] = {{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}, 
             {{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2}}, 
             {{3,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}},
             {{4,4,4},{4,4,4},{4,4,4}},
             {{5,5,5},{5,5,5},{5,5,5}},
             {{6,6,6},{6,6,6},{6,6,6}}};
```

`front` is a variable and is 1. This is where the problem lies, If I swap again and again, it will go to 4, then 5, then 6 etc. when I want it to go to 4, then 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, then 1 again because that's how much sides it has (not considering top and bottom).

How do you think I can accomplish this? I'm using C, not C++. I'll add any other information required. :)

Comment: There are untracked constraints in your representation. The cube is NOT 6 faces with each 9 squares. It is 9 + 8 + 9 pieces. Each corners have 3 fixed colors in a fixed pattern. Each side parts that are not corners have 2 colors. Only the centers are unconstrained thought ther can have an orientation. Whenever you rotate one slice, you also need to operate on all others but one faces. I'm afraid your core data model is wrong.

Comment: I think I'd rethink this.  Use `centerPiece`, `sidePiece`, and `cornerPiece` structs... or something.  Simply using a 3-d array isn't sufficient here.

Comment: @Sebastien This is really interesting, if you could inbox me some extra details, you'd be really saving me and my friend's headaches!

Comment: @Sebastien: +1 on your comment, but picking nits — a 3x3x3 Rubik's cube has 8 corners (each with three colours), 6 centres (each with one colour), and 12 side pieces (each with two colours), for 26 of 27 = 3^3 visible parts. I agree that 9+8+9 adds up to 26, but I'm mildly curious about the division you chose.  (My son also has 4x4x4, 5x5x5, ..., 11x11x11 cubes, plus dodecahedra, and other non-cubic Rubik's 'cubes'.)

Comment: This is all good to know. But do you think all of that matters if SOLVING the cube is not the main focus. The main focus is actually to just make a cube, which can rotate as it should. No need for algorithms to actually solve that. Only design.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I had 9 block on front and back faces and I removed the center block of the central face since it's not part of the cube problem itself. 9+8+9. My daugther counted it like you did ;). MegamanEXE, I'm not even close to consider writing the algorithm to solve it. Just the simplest memory representation possible. One of the challenges of writing computer programs is to break down the whole gig in sizeable chunks of manageable code. simplifying the initial representation is a good exercice itself and a HUGE investment for the future of the code.

Comment: @Sebastien: Oh; a completely different but equally valid way of looking at the cube.  Interesting!  Thanks for responding.

Comment: @MegamanEXE I started a little C project on gitorious if you want to look at it. It's only a framework at this point but I worked on the data model this weekend and should be able to update it soon. https://gitorious.org/c-cli-rubix-cube feel free to email me if you have questions. Please follow the repository guidelines before executing "push" on the repo.

Comment: @Sebastien I don't know what to say. I never expected any code, but it's really really great to see you actually took your time to do this. :D

Comment: I love to teach. And I take the occasion to work on that project with my daughter who's a HUGE rubic's cube fan :)

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use a rotator object like:

```
typedef struct
{
  int *values;
  int mod;
  int size; //if you want to generalize the rubiks..
}rotator;

void rotate(rotator *rotator)
{
  rotator->mod = (rotator->mod + 1) % rotator->size;
}

void print_rotator(rotator *rotator)
{
  int index;
  fprintf(stdout, "[");
  for(index = 0; index < rotator->size; ++index)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%d,", rotator->values[(index + rotator->mod) % rotator->size]);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "]\n");
}
```

Then you can have a think about how to build this into a n-ary cube..